# Custom Loss Function - Attention to small regions

Tags: tensorflow, keras, loss-function

I want to use a loss function which includes an expression for the area used by the attention model.

My model is a classification model, designed to perform the decision based on a small region of the original image.

So I would like my loss function to be:

```
Loss = categorical_crossentropy(y_pred, y_true) + alpha*A
```

where A is the area from the attention model.

How can I create a custom loss function in Keras, which minimizes the sum of the standard loss + some additional function?

Comment: How is the area defined? Segmentation? Bounding box with center and size? Other?

Comment: Bounding box with center and size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a model that outputs both things, `y_pred` and `A`:

```
#blablabla functional API model definition
model = Model(inputs, [predictions, areaOutput])
```

Make a custom area loss:

```
def areaLoss(trueArea, predArea):
    return predArea
```

Compile the model with one loss per output, and use `alpha` as the weight for the area loss:

```
model.compile(loss=['categorical_crossentropy', areaLoss], loss_weights=[1,alpha], ...)
```

Fit with a dummy value for the area as output:

```
model.fit(x_train, [y_train, np.zeros((totalSamples,))], ...)
```

Comment: That is a good answer, but not the one I was looking for. I do not have the GT location of the area in the image. I'm only interested in reducing some parametric value (which is linked to the total size of area)...

Comment: Make your model output this parametric value, that shouldn`t be hard to do.

Comment: Thank you, your solution was what I needed (I just read it to late in the evening to realize it yesterday).